# Python - Hide Console Mid-Way Through Script

Tags: python, console, terminal

Hopefully a simple answer. I have a console python program compiled to exe writing information constantly to the terminal, but half way through the script I'd like the terminal to hide but for the program to continue on hidden.

Is there a quick fix for this or is this more complicated then it seems? Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Which platform, Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a quick fix for this.

You could start without a window, fire up a subprocess with a console, and terminate that process when you want the console to go away.